# Return json value with php from swift iOS

Tags: php, ios, json

Hello I have a small a problem with the code below, Xcode print this error:

> ERROR: json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No
>   value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

SWIFT CODE:

```
let yourUrl=“mylink.php”
    let URL = NSURL(string:yourUrl)
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
    let boundaryConstant = "V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)
    let dataString = "Email=\(Email.text)&Password=\(Password.text)"
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        //reponse recieved
        //in this case response string will be saved in data, its of type NSData
        do{
            let str = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
            print(str)
        }
        catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }


    })
    task.resume()
```

PHP CODE:

mylink.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$email = $_POST["Email"];

$password = $_POST["Password"];

$stat=“myvalue”;

return json_encode($stat);

?>
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) should have array as a parameter, you are passing string over there.

Comment: @keviveks how do I change the code to make sure that it works ?